# Python permission denied problem on Mac os

Tags: python, macos, terminal, zsh, permission-denied

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur and Python IDLE 3.8.3

I started studying python recently so I don't know well about python

While studying about the library, I'm trying to learn `sys`

I m following the below steps -

- So I programed python file name `myargv` on /`Users/doit` folder
- And I go to terminal tab and I entered `/Users/doit python3 myargv.py`
- But I m facing the below error  - `zsh:permission denied: /Users/doit`

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a typo: You have a space after `doit`, which causes zsh to try to run `doit` instead of `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

Access the folder with `cd` and then run the python command:

```
cd path/to/file
python3 myargv.py
```

Or write the full path:

```
python3 path/to/file/myargv.py
```

Comment: Running that will give `command not found` error.

Comment: Try python instead. If it doesn't work, check that the python executable is in your path.

Comment: When I do like first code (with cd) program runs well. But second code have error even type with ./